# Wordpress, wrap posts in div

Tags: php, css, wordpress, styles

I'm quite new to wordpress, so bear with me. I have a site up and running allowing me to add content dynamically, the only problem is styling each post. I'm looking to wrap posts in a div, so images would be wrapped in one div and text posts would be wrapped in another, if that makes sense?
Here's some code I've been using:

```
<?php if ( in_category('photos') ) { ?>
           <div id="testing">
 <?php } else { ?>
           <div id="test-2">
 <?php } ?>
```

The only problem with this is that it wraps all posts in a given category and doesn't put a closing '< / div >' after the content, if that makes sense?

Comment: @Svetlio 'write your how code'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the only reason you're not getting any closing `</div>`s is because you're not putting it anywhere in your php.

This should work:

```
<?php while( have_posts() ) : the_post()
  if( in_category( 'photos' ) { ?>
    <div id="testing">
      // All your post content and whatnot
      <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
  <?php } else { ?>
    <div id="test-2">
      // All your post content
      <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
  <?php }
  endwhile; ?>
```

If you don't write complete markup in your theme files, you can't possibly expect Wordpress, or PHP, to automatically close your HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

"if that makes sense" No it doesn't really make sense as Wordpress by default adds a CSS-class for every category and tag to the surrounding `div`. If that is not the case in your theme, use the function `post_class()` to add the CSS-classes to your `div`.

See [the `post_class()`-documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class) for usage examples.